# Make a ROS2 program communicate with a Python program

Tags: ros, python, ros2, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We have Python program that has been developed by a team and is the core program.

This Python program calls a simulation made with ROS2, as a service, for some of the robot's moves.

We could put the Python program in a ROS2 node but this will make everything more complicated for the Python team. Including debugging.

We currently plan to have a web server to handle the communication between the two. One of the ROS2 nodes would be listening for requests from the Python program.

Or is there some "common way" to do that more efficiently?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410756/make-a-ros2-program-communicate-with-a-python-program/) by [thibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/109521/thibd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is existing work along these lines. You should look into the `rosbridge_suite`, which provides a websocket for external apps to communicate with the ros system. I don't know the status of this package for ros2, but a google search does return some hits. Here is the ros1 wiki page as a starting point:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2